# Write a query to find 2nd best word from the string using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have below table like this:

```
ID      Name
1       Ram played best And he best one
2       Shiv is best in reading and he is best player
3       X is best cook
```

I need to get the output like this:

```
ID     Second best word
1      one
2      player
3      n/a
```

I need to get the output whatever we have after 'best' word in the name string. Can anyone help me to crack this?

Comment: Are you using [tag:mysql] or [tag:sql-server], pick one

Comment: I'm using sql server

Comment: Please share your attempt

Answer (score 1):

XQuery makes this task simple.

XQuery is based on ordered sequences. Exactly what we need.

Notable points:

1. Input string is tokenized as XML (first `CROSS APPLY`).
2. XML element with the 2nd "best" word is found (second `CROSS APPLY`).
3. Finally, using its position we are getting very next word via `.value()` method.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, tokens VARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl (tokens) VALUES
('Ram played best And he best one'),
('Shiv is best in reading and he is best player'),
('X is best cook');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = SPACE(1);

SELECT ID, tokens
    , COALESCE(c.value('(/root/r[position()=sql:column("t2.x")]/text())[1]','VARCHAR(20)'), 'N/A') AS Result
FROM @tbl
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
        REPLACE(tokens, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
        ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT c.query('for $i in /root/r[./text()="best"][2]
        let $pos := count(root/*[. << $i]) + 2
        return $pos').value('.','INT')) AS t2(x);
```

**Output**

```
+----+-----------------------------------------------+--------+
| ID |                    tokens                     | Result |
+----+-----------------------------------------------+--------+
|  1 | Ram played best And he best one               | one    |
|  2 | Shiv is best in reading and he is best player | player |
|  3 | X is best cook                                | N/A    |
+----+-----------------------------------------------+--------+
```

Comment: plused you, but I think this can be done a bit simpler...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following;

```
select
    id,
    name,
    case
        when PATINDEX('%best %best %',name)= 0 then 'N/A'
        else SUBSTRING( 
                SUBSTRING(name, PATINDEX('%best %', name)+ 5, LEN(name)), 
                PATINDEX('%best %', SUBSTRING(name, PATINDEX('%best %', name)+ 5, LEN(name)))+ 5, 
                LEN(name) 
            ) 
        end
    from
        test
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split the string in to rows but that becomes tricky as SQL Server's *string_split* does not guarantee ordering.

This method uses *cross apply values* to pick out key elements of the string and should work whether the next word is the end of the string or not.

```
select Id,
    case when IsNull(b2,0)=0 then 'n/a' else
        Substring(name2,w, IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex(' ',name2,w),0),Len(name2))-w+1) 
    end SecondBestWord
from t
cross apply (values(CharIndex('best',name)))x(b1)
cross apply (values(Stuff(name,b1,4,'')))y(name2)
cross apply (values(CharIndex('best',name2)))z(b2)
cross apply (values(Iif(b2=0, 0, b2+5)))w(w)
```

[Example DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=42aadba9f7acdc06c84c807f2c713bc3)

Answer (score 0):

One more solution calling XQuery for rescue, but this might be a bit simpler. Especially the predicate `*[. << $i]` can be very slow with larger XMLs.

Using some more replacements we can achieve your needs with this:

(Credits for the sample data to Yitzhak Kabinsky)
I added one more line where your wanted word is not the last word and where there is another "best" in the sentence afterwards...

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, tokens VARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl (tokens) VALUES
('Ram played best And he best one'),
('Shiv is best in reading and he is best player'),
('X is best cook'),
('this is best example where best is not the end of the best sentence');
```

--the query

```
SELECT t.tokens
      ,A.x.value('best[3]/text()[1]','nvarchar(100)')
FROM @tbl t
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST(CONCAT('<best>',REPLACE(REPLACE(t.tokens,' best ','</best><best>'),' ','<blank/>'),'</best>') AS XML)) A(x);
```

One of the intermediate XMLs looks like this:

```
<best>Shiv<blank/>is</best>
<best>in<blank/>reading<blank/>and<blank/>he<blank/>is</best>
<best>player</best>
```

The idea in short:

- we use `" best "` to find the *buzz words* and any normal blank to separate the tokens within.
- Now we can pick the 3rd `<best>` (we added one more in the beginning), pick the first text() (which is NULL, if not existing).
- You can use `COALESCE()` to return "N/A" instead of NULL.

Hint:
Using `<blank/>` (=> self-closing tags) instead of the *blanks* allows us to address the `text()`-nodes beneath `<best>` by their index.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be this one

```
SELECT 
        ID,
        CASE 
            WHEN Name NOT LIKE '%best %best %' THEN 'n/a'
            ELSE REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(Name),CHARINDEX('tseb',REVERSE(Name))-2))
        END AS [Second best word]
FROM Table;
```

So first you check if there are two occurances of the word `best` and if so, then you reverse the whole string and look for the first occurance of `tseb` and reverse it again.

Maybe this is the solution you're looking for :)

EDIT: this would always pick the word after the **last** `best`. So if there are 20 occurances of `best` then you won't the the second one...

Comment: This will not only pick *the word after the last best* but everything that follows... The whole issue has some *homework* smell though :-)